# Livewire global store works with file and cache - but not with Session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Im making a deeply nested and reactive form renderer with Livewire. To do that I reached for a global store pattern, so any component in the hierarchy can refer to methods `getStore()` and `setStore($store)`.

It seem to work, I could implement the store getter/setter methods with the data residing either in a json file or by using the Cache facade. However, my first choice would be to use the session, something like:

```
public function getStore()

{
    return Session::get($this->store_id);
}

public function setStore($store)
{
    Session::put($this->store_id, $store);
}
```

But, I can't get this to work specifically with Session. Have a hard time debugging why that is. It seems sometimes a session key is not set when it should, even though logging indicating it was set without any errors. I also tried explicitly persisting it with `Session::save();` in case it does not reach the Terminable Middleware where it is normally persisted. No effect.

Any ideas why my store setup works with file_get_contents/Cache but not with Session?

Answer (score 2):

Same happened to me. After refreshing the page, session would appear with old data. I even tried using setter with `Session::forget()` function, but it didn't work.

```
private function set($cart)
    {
        Session::forget('cart');
        Session::put('cart', $cart);
        Session::save();
    }
```

There was no error and logging data with `Log::debug('after-set' . request()->session()->get('cart')['products'])` and `Log::debug('after-page-refresh' . request()->session()->get('cart')['products'])` displayed 2 different arrays. Only thing that I found consistent is that after page refresh – only last `Session::put()` request was not saved – all other changes before it took effect.
I'll probably have to use Cache like you did, because such inconsistency is to risky for production.